# Java GraphQL Spring Boot Apollo federation issue with reference resolver

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql-java, apollo-federation

I am trying to get Apollo federation working with two GraphQL services using Java/Spring Boot and graphql-kickstart. Consider the following schemas:

Person Service:

```
type Person @key(fields: "id") {
  id: String!
  name: String!
}
```

Book Service:

```
type Book @key(fields: "id") {
  id: String!
  author: Person!
}

type Person @extends @key(fields: "id") {
  id: String! @external
}
```

I am trying to run a query such as:

```
query {
  book(bookId:"1") {
    author {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the query against the Apollo gateway, the query it runs against the Person service is:

```
query ($representations:[_Any!]!) {
  _entities(representations:$representations) {
    ... on Person {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

with variables:

```json
{
  "representations": [
    {
      "__typename": "Person",
      "id": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is returning:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "_entities": [null]
  }
}
```

GraphQL configuration (class with @Configuration annotation) has the following (taken from the example at https://github.com/setchy/graphql-java-kickstart-federation-example/blob/master/shows/src/main/java/com/example/demo/federation/FederatedSchema.java):

```java
    @Bean
    public GraphQLSchema customSchema(SchemaParser schemaParser) {
        GraphQLSchema federatedSchema = Federation.transform(schemaParser.makeExecutableSchema())
            .fetchEntities(env -> env.<List<Map<String, Object>>>getArgument(_Entity.argumentName)
                .stream()
                .map(reference -> {
                    return null;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .resolveEntityType(env -> {
                return null;
            })
            .build();

        return federatedSchema;
    }
```

According to the Apollo documentation at https://www.apollographql.com/docs/federation/entities/#2-define-a-reference-resolver the .fetchEntities method should add a reference resolver that resolves the type. However, I'm unsure how to do this in a static context, and in the example linked above this is not done (although I'm unable to get the example to work due to a separate issue).

Any ideas to help point out what's wrong are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not contributing any fields to the Person, I think you need to define it like this

Book Service:

```
type Book @key(fields: "id") {
  id: String!
  author: Person!
}

type Person @extends @key(fields: "id", resolvable: false) {
  id: String!
}
```